# Java prepared statement throwing SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Invalid argument(s) in call

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to insert a record into DB (Oracle) through Java code. When it is preparing statement at that time it is throwing an exception

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Invalid argument(s) in call

on below line of code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
```

and the insert query is:

```java
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO ABC ( uid,created_datetime,status,update_datetime,b_id,ref_no,ref_dt,sor,b1_id,c_code,base,name,src,trn_date,country,pr,cv,features,scoring_time_ms,scoring_request_time_ms,preprocessing_time_ms,postprocessing_time_ms,overall_time_ms )VALUES ( ?,current_timestamp,?,current_timestamp,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,current_timestamp,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";
```

When I debugged the code I found that when it is preparing statement `connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);` insert query is showing as below:

```
INSERT INTO ABC ( uid,created_datetime,status,update_datetime,b_id,ref_no,ref_dt,sor,b1_id,c_code,base,name,src,trn_date,country,pr,cv,features,scoring_time_ms,scoring_request_time_ms,preprocessing_time_ms,postprocessing_time_ms,overall_time_ms )VALUES ( ?,systimestamp,?,systimestamp,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
```

It is changing current_timestamp to systimestamp and also I have 3 current_timestamp in the query and it is missing 3rd one while debugging.

I have deleted all the records from database. DB is empty and it has no constraints, only primary key.

Can anyone help me on this issue. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `systimestamp` and `current_timestamp` are the same in Oracle

Comment: That's correct but why is it replacing this? It should not replace it.

Comment: How exactly are you getting the SQL string after the prepare?

Comment: on this line PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY); itself it throws an exception with insert_query above I posted.

Comment: And that shows the `systimestamp` instead of `current_Timestamp` - that can only happen if your code changed the string variable.

Comment: Have you listed all fields (that are not generated automatically)? Dump the entire stacktrace. It could very well being a failed JDBC connection or such; where the oracle driver was missing. _Should this be the first SQL statement._

Comment: 07 Oct 19 19:22:34 | 2881882[           main] support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator [] | Translating SQLException with SQL state '23000', error code '1', message [Invalid argument(s) in call]; SQL was [] for task [PreparedStatementCallback]

Comment: Does the exception contain an ORA id? Could you post the full trace.

Comment: Actually I am running it through tool in my organization so it is showing only this in the console. But when I debugged then I got that exception on that line.

Comment: Do you know what values its trying to insert, the error cannot be on connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY), since a statement is being generated. There could be a violation in the data being inserted with the statement.

Comment: No, It's throwing an exception at this line only.

Comment: Please post the DDL of the table and the part of the code that sets the bind variables, e.g. `ps.setInt(1,id)`  - here is the most probable cause of the problem.

Comment: Post also the JDBC Driver version and the full exception stack. Note that there are few bugs on MOS with this signature e.g. [26051289](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?_afrLoop=206279988336805&id=26051289&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=6gt9ztyek_85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. It was build issue. It was not taking updated code so getting that error. Deleted everything from .m2 dir and build it again and this error got disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException points to a db constraint violation. Check the for primary/unique/foreign keys in the table "ABC". Just based on the insert statement, can assume uid must be unique.

Comment: Hi @Martin I have deleted all the records from database. DB is empty and it has no constraints, only primary key.

Comment: @Martin'sRun most probably not relevant. Eg on PK violation you get `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (....) violated`